# List of all classes exported by a flash movie

Tags: flash, export, assert, movieclip, moviecliploader

A Flash movie loads another movie that contains various asserts - movie clips in its library with 'Export for Action Script' settings set.

Is there any way to determine the list of class names of all these exported asserts from within the movie that loads them?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you cannot do that in Flash.

You can check if a given class is present using [ApplicationDomain::hasDefinition()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/system/ApplicationDomain.html#hasDefinition())

Comment: @Amarghosh Thank you. Do you think it's a security measure or a feature lack?

I kind of found a way around by placing instances of all classes on the stage and then scanning its children, but it means the designer I'm working with has to remember to do that every time he adds a new class to the library.

Comment: I don't see why that would help security - neither can I think of a reason to have reflection at such deep levels. Do other languages like java/c# have this feature? What is your use case anyway?

Comment: @Amarghosh The designer I work with provides me with the a .swf file that contains various asserts, each having a unique export class. I simply need to know what these classes are without examining .fla.